# Pivot in SQL for negative values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].(test)
            [cid] [varchar](50) NULL,
            [mid] [varchar](50) NULL,
            [val] [varchar](50) NULL
  ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Table Structure(select * form test)

```
cid     mid val
h0609   c01 -213
h0609   c02 -7
h0609   c03 0
h0702   c01 -4
h0702   c04 -3
```

I need output in this format

```
cid     c01   c02    c03    c04
h0609   -213    -7   0      NULL
h0702   -4    NULL   NULL   -3
h1171   NULL  NULL  -212     -117
h1272   -9    NULL   NULL   NULL
h1273   6     NULL   NULL   NULL
```

Query which Im tried(but its giving null value)

```
SELECT cid, mid,[c01],[c02],[c03],[c04]
FROM [dbo].[test] 
PIVOT( max(val) 
  FOR val IN ([c01],[c02],[c03],[c04]) ) AS P
```

I got output like this

```
cid     mid c01     c02     c03     c04
h0609   c01 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
h0702   c01 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
h1272   c01 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
h1273   c01 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I need output in this format

```
 cid    c01   c02    c03    c04
 h0609  -213    -7   0      NULL
 h0702  -4    NULL   NULL   -3
 h1171  NULL  NULL  -212     -117
 h1272  -9    NULL   NULL   NULL
 h1273  6     NULL   NULL   NULL
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with negative values.  The problem is the `pivot`:

```
SELECT cid, mid,[c01],[c02],[c03],[c04]
FROM [dbo].[test] 
PIVOT( max(val) 
  FOR val IN ([c01],[c02],[c03],[c04]) ) AS P
------^
```

That should be `mid`; `val` doesn't take on those values.

Comment: Can yu tell me how to do this in DB2

Comment: That is a different question, and should be asked as a question, not a comment.  I wonder why this was downvoted.